# How to use react-router to update an edit form in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, react-router, frontend

I want to create an edit form so that I can be able to edit a contact, and update it using `react-router`. I passed in the state through the router link, then I receive it using the `useLocation`. But the problem I am facing right now is that I do not know how to use the received data to initialize my form when I click on any contact to edit. I meant, if I should click on edit, it should load the information on that contact I click on, then I will update it.

This is where I pass in the state to the edit button

```
import classes from './ContactItem.module.css'
import { Fragment, useState} from 'react'
import CustomButton from '../UI/CustomButton'
import {Link} from 'react-router-dom'
import {BiEdit} from 'react-icons/bi'
import {RiDeleteBinLine} from 'react-icons/ri'
import DeleteContact from '../UI/DeleteContact'

const ContactItem = (props) => {
  const { id, firstName, lastName, phone, email} = props.contact;
    
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const handleShow = () => {
    setShow(true);
  }

  return (
    <Fragment >
      <div className={classes.container}>
        <div className={classes.name}>
          <div>{firstName}</div>
          <div>{lastName}</div>
        </div>
        <div className={classes.utilities}>
          <div className={classes.contact}>
            <div className={classes.email}>{email}</div>
            <div className={classes.phone}>{phone}</div>
          </div> 
          <div className={classes.utility}>
            <Link to={`/edit/${id}`} state={props.contact }>
              <div className={classes.edit}>
                <BiEdit />
              </div>
            </Link>
            <div className={classes.delete}>
              <RiDeleteBinLine onClick={handleShow} />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
                
        <hr className={classes.hr}/>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.button}>
        <Link to={`/${id}`}>
          <CustomButton>view Details</CustomButton>
        </Link>
      </div>
            
      <DeleteContact show={show} setShow={setShow} onDelete={id} />
    </Fragment>
  )
}

export  default ContactItem
```

The below code is where I receive the data that is passed through the link. This is also the editForm components. I am using custom hook for my edit form component

```
import React from 'react'
import useInput from '../formHooks/hooks/use-input'
import './EditForm.css'
import LoadingSpinner from './LoadingSpinner'
import {useLocation} from 'react-router-dom'

const EditForm = (props) => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const data = location.state;
  console.log(data)

  const {
    value: enteredFirstName,
    isValid: enteredFirstNameIsValid,
    hasError: firstNameInputHasError,
    InputBlurHandler: firstNameBlurHandler,
    valueChangeHandler: firstNameChangedHandler,
    reset: resetFirstNameInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() !== "")
     
  const {
    value: enteredLastName,
    isValid: enteredLastNameIsValid,
    hasError: lastNameInputHasError,
    InputBlurHandler: lastNameBlurHandler,
    valueChangeHandler: lastNameChangedHandler,
    reset: resetLastNameInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() !== "")
    
  const {
    value: enteredEmail,
    isValid: enteredEmailIsValid,
    hasError: emailInputHasError,
    InputBlurHandler: emailBlurHandler,
    valueChangeHandler: emailChangedHandler,
    reset: resetEmailInput
  } = useInput(value => value.includes('@'))

  const {
    value: enteredPhoneNumber,
    isValid: enteredPhoneNumberIsValid,
    hasError: phoneNumberInputHasError,
    InputBlurHandler: phoneNumberBlurHandler,
    valueChangeHandler: phoneNumberChangedHandler,
    reset: resetPhoneNumberInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() !== "")

  const {
    value: enteredAddress1,
    isValid: enteredAddress1IsValid,
    hasError: address1InputHasError,
    InputBlurHandler: address1BlurHandler,
    valueChangeHandler: address1ChangedHandler,
    reset: resetAddress1Input
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() !== "")

  const {
    value: enteredAddress2,
    valueChangeHandler: address2ChangedHandler,
    reset: resetAddress2Input
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() == "")

  const {
    value: enteredState,
    valueChangeHandler: stateChangedHandler,
    reset: resetStateInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() == "")


  const {
    value: enteredCountry,
    valueChangeHandler: countryChangedHandler,
    reset: resetCountryInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() == "")

  const {
    value: enteredFile,
    valueChangeHandler: fileChangedHandler,
    reset: resetFileInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() == "")

  const {
    value: enteredAbout,
    isValid: enteredAboutIsValid,
    hasError: aboutInputHasError,
    InputBlurHandler: aboutBlurHandler,
    valueChangeHandler: aboutChangedHandler,
    reset: resetAboutInput
  } = useInput(value => value.trim() !== "")
    
  let formIsValid = false
    
  if (enteredFirstNameIsValid
    && enteredEmailIsValid
    && enteredLastNameIsValid
    && enteredPhoneNumberIsValid
    && enteredAddress1IsValid
    && enteredAboutIsValid
  ) {
    formIsValid = true 
  } else {
    formIsValid = false
  } 
    
  const formSubmitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
        
    if (!enteredFirstNameIsValid
      && !enteredLastNameIsValid
      && !enteredEmailIsValid
      && !enteredPhoneNumberIsValid
      && !enteredAddress1IsValid
      && !enteredAboutIsValid
    ) {
      return;
    }
    
    resetFirstNameInput();
    resetEmailInput();
    resetLastNameInput();
    resetPhoneNumberInput();
    resetAddress1Input();
    resetAddress2Input();
    resetStateInput();
    resetCountryInput();
    resetFileInput();
    resetAboutInput();

    props.onSaveContact({
      firstName: enteredFirstName,
      lastName: enteredLastName,
      email: enteredEmail,
      phone: enteredPhoneNumber,
      address1: enteredAddress1,
      address2: enteredAddress2,
      state: enteredState,
      country: enteredCountry,
      file: enteredFile,
      about: enteredAbout
    })
  }
    
  const firstNameInputClasses = firstNameInputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control'
  const emailInputClasses = emailInputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control'
  const lastNameInputClasses = lastNameInputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control'
  const phoneNumberInputClasses = phoneNumberInputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control'
  const address1InputClasses = address1InputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control'
  const aboutInputClasses = aboutInputHasError ? 'form-control invalid' : 'form-control'



  return (
    <form onSubmit={formSubmitHandler}>
      <div className='container'>

        {props.isLoading && (
          <div className='loading'>
            <LoadingSpinner />
          </div>
        )}
        <div className='control-group'>
          <div className={firstNameInputClasses}>
            <label htmlFor='firstName'>First Name</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              id='firstName' 
              onChange={firstNameChangedHandler}
              onBlur={firstNameBlurHandler}
              value={enteredFirstName}
            />
            {firstNameInputHasError && 
              <p className="error-text">First Name must not be empty</p>
            }
          </div>
          <div className={lastNameInputClasses}>
            <label htmlFor="lastName">Last Name</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              id="lastName" 
              onChange={lastNameChangedHandler}
              onBlur={lastNameBlurHandler}
              value={enteredLastName}
            />
            {lastNameInputHasError && 
              <p className="error-text">Enter a valid name</p>
            }
          </div>
        </div>    
        <div className={emailInputClasses}>
          <label htmlFor='email'>Email Address</label>
          <input
            type='email'
            id='email' 
            onChange={emailChangedHandler}
            onBlur={emailBlurHandler}
            value={enteredEmail}
          />
          {emailInputHasError && 
            <p className="error-text">Enter a valid email</p>
          }
        </div>
        <div className={phoneNumberInputClasses}>
          <label htmlFor='phoneNumber'>Phone Number</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            inputMode='numeric' 
            onChange={phoneNumberChangedHandler}
            onBlur={phoneNumberBlurHandler}
            value={enteredPhoneNumber}
          />
          {phoneNumberInputHasError && 
            <p className="error-text">Number must not be empty</p>
          }
        </div>
        <div className={address1InputClasses}>
          <label htmlFor='address1'>Address 1</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            id='address1' 
            onChange={address1ChangedHandler}
            onBlur={address1BlurHandler}
            value={enteredAddress1}
          />
          {address1InputHasError && 
            <p className="error-text">Address must not be empty</p>
          }
        </div>
        <div className='form-control'>
          <label htmlFor='address2'>Address 2</label>
          <input
            type='text'
            id='address2' 
            onChange={address2ChangedHandler}
            value={enteredAddress2}
          />        
        </div>
        <div className='country'>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <label htmlFor="country">Country</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              id='country' 
              onChange={countryChangedHandler}
              value={enteredCountry}
            />  
          </div>
          <div className='form-control'>
            <label htmlFor="state">State</label>
            <input
              type='text'
              id='state' 
              onChange={stateChangedHandler}
              value={enteredState}
            />  
          </div>
        </div>
        <div className='form-control'>
          <label htmlFor="file">Select Image</label>
          <input
            type='file'
            id="file"
            onChange={fileChangedHandler}
            value={enteredFile}
          />  
        </div>
        <div className={aboutInputClasses}>
          <label htmlFor='about'>About</label>
          <textarea
            type='text'
            id='about'
            rows='5'
            cols='50' 
            onChange={aboutChangedHandler}
            onBlur={aboutBlurHandler}
            value={enteredAbout}
          />
          {aboutInputHasError && 
            <p className="error-text">Your input text must not below 100 characters</p>
          }
        </div>
        <div className='form-actions'>
          <button disabled={!formIsValid}>Update</button>
          <button>Cancel</button>
        </div>
      </div>  
    </form>
  )
}

export default EditForm
```

Below is the custom hook code I am using for the form

```
import { useState } from "react";

const useInput = (validateValue) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState('')
  const [isTouched, setIsTouched] = useState(false)

  const valueIsValid = validateValue(enteredValue);
  const hasError = !valueIsValid && isTouched;

  const valueChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setEnteredValue(e.target.value)
    // setEnteredNameIsValid(true)
  }

  const InputBlurHandler = (e) => {
    setIsTouched(true)
  }

  const reset = () => {
    setEnteredValue('');
    setIsTouched(false)
  }
   
  return {
    value: enteredValue, 
    isValid: valueIsValid,
    hasError, 
    valueChangeHandler, 
    InputBlurHandler,
    reset
  }
};

export default useInput;
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic gist is that you need to pass the passed route state value(s) to the form state. Ideally you'd want to initialize the field state to a value instead of an empty string. You could try the following refactor.

```
const useInput = ({
  initialValue = '',
  validateValue = () => true,
}) => {
  const [enteredValue, setEnteredValue] = useState(initialValue || '');
  const [isTouched, setIsTouched] = useState(false);

  const valueIsValid = validateValue(enteredValue);
  const hasError = !valueIsValid && isTouched;

  const valueChangeHandler = (e) => {
    setEnteredValue(e.target.value);
    // setEnteredNameIsValid(true);
  };

  const InputBlurHandler = (e) => {
    setIsTouched(true);
  };

  const reset = () => {
    setEnteredValue(initialValue);
    setIsTouched(false);
  };
   
  return {
    value: enteredValue, 
    isValid: valueIsValid,
    hasError, 
    valueChangeHandler, 
    InputBlurHandler,
    reset
  };
};
```

...

```
const location = useLocation();
const data = location.state;

const {
  value: enteredFirstName,
  isValid: enteredFirstNameIsValid,
  hasError: firstNameInputHasError,
  InputBlurHandler: firstNameBlurHandler,
  valueChangeHandler: firstNameChangedHandler,
  reset: resetFirstNameInput
} = useInput({
  initialValue: data.firstName,
  validateValue: value => value.trim() !== "",
});

...
```

Comment: Ok, will get back to u. Thanks so much

Comment: @Duke Welcome. Had you a chance to try this pattern out?

Comment: It definitely work. I'm so happy. But remains the update function, how to create and update the form. I will be expecting it

Comment: @Duke Great! Glad to hear. Is the part about the update function related to the code in this question? In other words, is your question here still not totally resolved? Could you create a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) of this minimal example that we could take a look at and inspect live?

Comment: The previous question is resolved. I wanted to solve another problem which is updating of the form. I would use it to update the form. You can check the previous question, you the components that will have the updated function is there. Waiting for your response

Comment: @Duke Sorry, what previous question are you referring to? What is the other problem? Have you created a new post regarding any other extraneous issues relating to updating the form?